# There are 12 train stops between New York and Boston. How many tickets are to be printed to travel between any of the two stations...?

Tags: combinatorics

There are 12 train stops between New York and Boston. How many train tickets are to be printed, so that a person can travel between any of the two stations (irrespective of the direction of travel)?

I've solved it as $\binom{12}{2}$ problem arriving at $66$ tickets. Apparently, 66 is scored as the wrong answer.

[image]

How to solve this problem or it is incorrect to score the answer as wrong?

Comment: You left out the starting and ending stations (NY and Boston). So that makes it 2$\binom{14}{2}$ because you need to travel both ways (forward and return).

Comment: The question did not say Newyork and Boston are stations, it just said between. Hence took it for literal meaning. My bad. I think questions like this can be evaluated in the best interest of the evaluator...

Comment: Therein lies the frustration with automated scoring systems like this.  You often are not given an opportunity to ask for clarification and correct answers to different interpretations often are not given partial (or full) credit.  Had this been scored by hand and you had been able to justify your answer I would have gladly given full credit.  What is being graded here is your understanding of binomial coefficients, not English and trying to intuit whether the NY station was among the 12 mentioned stops or separate from those 12 stops, or even among the available choices for the "two stations"

Comment: The phrasing as pictured is ambiguous and I could see any of $\binom{12}{2},2\binom{12}{2},\binom{14}{2},2\binom{14}{2}$ as correct answers.  As commented below, the "*irrespective of direction of travel*" phrase does make it sound like we might have wanted to count "forward" tickets the same as "return" tickets... but also possible is that the phrase was there to emphasize that our fictional person is allowed to travel either direction and was not there to state those tickets should be considered the same.  In the end, this is a badly written question and I sympathize with you.  Good luck.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig To be clear, $\binom{14}{2} = 91$ while $2\binom{14}{2}=14\times 13 = 182$.  The "accepted" answer of $182$ corresponds to the number of ways of selecting two of 14 stations with one as a start and another as an end.

Comment: @JMoravitz Of course, you are correct.  The question is unclear since the accepted answer does not match the phrase "irrespective of the direction of travel."